# How to locate directory resource in Xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am currently working with Xamarin.iOS and trying to fetch data from directory inside in my project resource and project directory. But I am not able to get data while fetching information. I can even see the whole directory is not copied in application bundle itself.

Below is my code.

```
string localHtmlUrl = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath,
                                   string.Format("NewFolder/webref/index.html")
                      );
```

Comment: Any luck with this? are you able to show where your files are like in the screenshot below?

Answer (score 5):

From this [sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/web_view/load_local_content/) I think all you need is this:

```
string fileName = "NewFolder/webref/index.html"; // remember case-sensitive
string localHtmlUrl = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, fileName);
webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(localHtmlUrl, false)));
```

If you have a folder structure like this:

[image]

If it is in your `Resource` folder then you will need to put that in your path like so:

```
string fileName = "Resource/NewFolder/webref/index.html";
```

**Remember** to set the `Build Action` to `BundleResource` for all files.

Could also try this:

```
var fileName = "NewFolder/webref/index.html";
webView.LoadHtmlString (File.ReadAllText (fileName), NSUrl.FromFilename (fileName));
```

Comment: Thanks lain for guiding me here, I found problem that I have directory structure which I added in my xamarin.ios project, but while debugging I can see full directory structure is not copied in app bundle. So in this case I am not able to get desired file index.html.

Comment: Did you set the Build Action to BundleResource for all files?

Comment: For me Its working now, Thanks lain for helping me, I have to select all the files inside in each directory then provide action appropriately and access folder.

Comment: Awesome glad it worked! If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers.